# On a strange integral

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, summation

The following integral came into my way today.

$${\Large \int_{0}^{\infty} }\frac{\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}k\sin(kx)\,e^{-tk^2}}{\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx)\,e^{-tk^2}}dt=\frac{\pi^2({\pi-x})}{8} \quad , \quad 0<x<2\pi$$

I have no idea how to attack it. First thing coming into my mind is Poisson summation formula but I am not used to using it.. So, basically no clue.

Can we deduce a general form for those two sums in there? I have this strange feeling we can , no?

By the way, since I don't have an attack I am not sure the answer is correct.

Comment: Note that: $$\frac d{dx}\cos(kx)=-k\sin(kx)$$ May come in handy, haven't thought about it much.

Comment: Looks like a quotient of theta-functions...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yeah, I had seen that my self.. but at this stage of the problem which is the beginning I don't see how it helps?

Comment: @Chappers I beg your pardon? Thetas? What is related to thetas?

Comment: @Tolaso: $\sum_{k\geq 1} e^{-tk^2}$ is a Theta.

Comment: Ho ho ho , well well well , very nice!! No way I am solving it!! Good to know!

Comment: Mind I ask where you found the solution?

Comment: The integrand function is of the form $-\frac{f_x}{f}$, hence by integrating with respect to $x$ we get that the integral depends on the logarithm of a theta-like series. My bet is so on a consequence of the Jacobi triple product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product)

Comment: You mean the closed form? Well the problem is stated like this in the leaflet our professor hand out to us today. He said there will be challenging problems but I did not expect them to be that tough!!

Comment: However, in order to bring $$\prod_{m=1}^\infty\left( 1 - x^{2m}\right)\left( 1 + x^{2m-1} y^2\right)\left( 1 +\frac{x^{2m-1}}{y^2}\right)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{n^2} y^{2n}\tag{1}$$ to its extreme consequences, I would be happier to have $1+2\sum_{k\geq 1}\cos(kx)e^{-tk^2}$ in the denominator.

Comment: Jack , give the version you mention a try !!! You never know what you shall find !!

Comment: Does not seem to be true when $x=0$ ... Jack's suggestion that the sums should be $ \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ might work ?

Answer (score 3):

Houston, we have a problem. The given integral is not well defined: for many fixed values of $x\in(0,2\pi)$, the function

$$ g(t)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\cos(kx)e^{-tk^2} $$
has a simple zero in a right neighbourhood of the origin that is not shared by $\sum_{k\geq 1}k\sin(kx)e^{-tk^2}$.
Simple poles are not integrable singularities, hence the LHS is not well-defined for any $x$ in the range $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: How about if we go with the version you propose ??

Comment: @Tolaso: before starting a massive amount of probably pointless computations, I would prefer to receive some clarification about the original problem. Can you show to your professor my remark?

Comment: Sure !!! However tomorrow !!! It's past midnight here !!

Comment: @Tolaso: no problem, there is no hurry. We will keep in touch.

Comment: Hey Jack ... the professor says that he may mistyped the problem and the version you mention is probably the correct one ... he has no further comments this time !!